# Is "毁灭" the best word to use here?

Tags: usage

I am trying to translate this sentence:

> Explore a beautiful, vast and ruined world riddled with dangers and lost technologies.

After consulting Google Translate, this is what I came up with:

> 探索一个美丽，充满危险和丢失的科技，广阔而**毁灭**的世界。

Is "毁灭" the best term to use here? I found a lot of translations for "ruined" (such as "废墟" & "破败") and I'm not sure which one is appropriate in this context.

Comment: Among the three, maybe 破败 is best.

Comment: 废土 is a concise translation of “the ruined world”, such as the world in the game fallout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

毁灭 = 'to destroy'

'ruined' here is an adjective that means '毁灭了的/ **残破的**'

'**ruined world**' = 毁灭了的世界/ **残破的世界**

> Explore a beautiful, vast, and ruined world riddled with dangers and **lost** technologies.

> 探索一个美丽(的)，广阔而残破(的)，充满危险和失落(的)科技的世界。

The term 'lost technologies' is usually translated as 失落的科技 or 遗失的科技. '丢失' is more suitable for a recent event; 失落的/ 遗失的 is more suitable for a distant event

Either 残破的世界 or 破败的世界 is better than 毁灭的世界

- 美丽的世界
- 广阔而残破的世界
- 充满危险和遗失的科技的世界
- 探索一个美丽，广阔而残破，充满危险和遗失科技的世界。

When putting the three above phrases together to form a single sentence, you can just keep the last 的 and omit the rest. The  的 before 世界 serves as the adjectival marker for all the adjectives in this sentence

More example:

- 好看的车
- 贵价的车
- 全新的车
- 好看，贵价，全新的车

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the word suggestion and such a thorough breakdown!

I didn't know that about putting adjectives together. I thought the sentence looked a little funny but didn't know why.

Comment: Thank you for the additional example!

Comment: @furrygecko 好看的，贵价的，全新的车 is also grammatical. You can keep all the 的 if you want to emphasize each adjective individually.

Comment: I will keep that in mind when I try again!